# how to count the elements entered by the user in python?

Tags: python

I have a program that appends to a list repeadly  numbers entered by the user using a while loop. My goal is to count the amount of elements entered by the user. To count the elements of the list,I used the len() function. Is there any other way to count the amount of elements entered by the user without appending them to a list? My code is below:

```
L=[]

while True:
    n=input('digite um numero: ')

    if n== 'done':
        break
    try:
        L.append (float(n)) 
    except ValueError:
        print(' erro')
```

Comment: You could just use a count variable and increment it with each user input

Comment: A simple counter?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to increment a variable by one each time an input is being done, the variable should be outside of the loop - like so:

```
counter = 0

while True:
    user_input=input('Enter a number or type exit')
    
    if user_input == 'exit':
        break
    
    counter += 1
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP does not want to count when `n='done'`

Comment: This solution adds one more than it should.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
count = 0
while True:
    n=input('digite um numero: ')

    if n== 'done':
        break
    count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Comment: If this helped you, don't forget to accept this answer for others to see in the future.